# Send email when an episode airs

Tags: php, perl, email, cron

**Background:**

I'm working on a site that lists television shows of the current and upcoming seasons, complete with countdowns to the next episode on each. For these shows, I have a table of shows, and a table of corresponding episodes (one row for each episode, each has the correct air date).

Now, I would also like to allow users to opt-in to email updates on any series of their choosing. So, I have a table that contains emails and which series' updates to send to that email. The emails would be simple notifications such as "Such and such series has been announced to air this fall." or "Episode 3 of Such and such series is now available."

I'm confident that I can make a script that would find episodes that aired within the last 30 minutes, and loop through and email anyone who has opted to be notified. But, I'm unsure of how to accomplish the actual execution automatically. I'd like the emails to be sent as close to the time of their relevance as possible, rather than a weekly roundup. The shows are foreign, meaning I won't be able to execute a script myself due to odd air times, though I'd prefer automation anyways.

**My questions:**

1. In my various searches I've come across cron jobs - is this really the best way to do it?
2. Would it running every 30 minutes be a bad idea?
3. My site is currently using PHP, but from what I've read, it's inefficient for emailing. So, would Perl be a good language to use for the emailing? If not, which language should I use? (Ideally a more common and well established language)

Comment: I thinks cron jobs is a good idea. Or, if you know youhave enough visits, you could check for events when users request pages.

Comment: If you need something do every 30 minutes... doing something every 30 minutes is the only way to solve it so cron away. AFAIK anything that an be done in perl can be done in PHP, i'd be interested to know if there is a drop off in PHP's capabilities over perl's (interesting fact... php started out as a collection of perl cgi scripts).

Comment: Also I have developed and used both php and perl bulk mail scripts and from a performance standpoint my experience showed little to no difference in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Your precision does not require to be accurate to the second it shouldn't need to be run on say a `.sh` script or a small listener.

   However, if you do intend to have the update more accurate, you may use something like:

   script.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   while [ 1 ]
   do
       php -q "/path/to/mail.php"
       sleep 5000
   done
   ```

   In this example, you may call your script at five second intervals.
2. No. If you have scripted the PHP to loop efficiently through the database (ex. not with php loops, but with sql joins), then running the script at lower intervals would work too.

   PHP loops would mean like:

   ```
   foreach ($users as $user) {
       $mysqli->query("SELECT `shows` FROM `user_shows` WHERE `id`=".$user->id);
   }
   ```

   Where as SQL Join would be better.

   ```
   SELECT `shows` FROM `user_shows` JOIN `users` ON user.id = user_shows.user_id;
   ```
3. No. `mail` uses the settings defined in another location and efficiency would be determined by the efficiency of your mail server/service.

   Moreover, you don't even need to use the default `mail` function in PHP either. You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or an third party service such as [FeedBurner](https://feedburner.google.com).

Comment: It highly depends on what you would like. As for me, I think when a new episode of my favorite show released, I would want the precision to be close to the hour. So 30 minutes is pretty reasonable. Cron jobs should suffice no doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and examples. I'll stick with PHP, and use a cron job. You've even helped put my mind at ease on this project, heh.